# How to containerize a Angular service in a full-stack app?

Tags: angular, docker, docker-compose, angular-cli, dockerfile

I'm new to Docker and containerization. I have a spring boot app for backend service and front-end uses AngularCLI/Angular4. I tried below code to containerize angular service and running docker-compose up command is giving the following error:

> Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found. Error: Local
>   workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found.
>   at WorkspaceLoader._getProjectWorkspaceFilePath (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/workspace-loader.js:44:19)

Here is my
Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8.11-alpine as node-angular-cli

WORKDIR src/main/java/frontend

RUN npm install -g @angular/cli

EXPOSE 4200

CMD ["ng", "serve", "--proxy", "-", "config", "proxy.conf.json"]
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3'

services:

  db:
      image: mysql:latest
      restart: always
      environment:
        MYSQL_DATABASE: root
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        MYSQL_USER: root
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
      ports:
        - "3306:3306"
  angular:
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      ports:
        - "4200:4200"
```

Is there a better way to containerize this application? I was successful in containerizing the whole application but it seems the front-end part doesn't work as surely I didn't include the configuration required for angular service to be up and running( ng serve cmd and its related install details) when containerizing and thus, creating a new DockerFile (shown above)? Can I just have 1 Dockerfile serving the purpose for running both these services?

Comment: You're not copying any files into your docker image. You will likely want something like `COPY . .`. See the docs for more details https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy

Comment: Event though I used COPY . . it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: I would try not using `ng serve` in the docker image, but instead build the angular app and then use something like NGINX to serve that app. Here's an example: https://www.prestonlamb.com/blog/dockerizing-angular. You can use a multi-step docker build process to achieve it. I've been using this configuration for a while now and it works well for me with docker compose and docker stack.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following steps in my `Dockerfile` to containerize my Angular apps.

```
FROM johnpapa/angular-cli as angular-built
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json package.json
RUN npm install --silent
COPY . .
RUN ng build --prod

FROM nginx:alpine
LABEL author="Preston Lamb" 
COPY --from=angular-built /usr/src/app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80 443
CMD [ "nginx", "-g", "daemon off;" ]
```

The first step builds the Angular image (this example has the `--prod` flag, but you could change it to `--env=test`, for example) then copies that built application into an image that's based on NGINX to serve the application.

Comment: Thanks pjlamb12 for response. I'll try it but now I'm also thinking instead of putting angular service part in docker-compose.yaml ; I could just do in DockerFile. But is it possible that I can just have 1 DockerFile for both backend and front-end? [My back-end service is basically a spring boot app].